# Seared Sushi Bishul Yisroel

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, sources-mekorot, cooking-bishul

Certain Sushi require the searing of the fish on the outside. Does this process require a Jew light the torch used to do the searing or is it not required? I have seen that some stores do and some do not. what is the opinion of the Big national Hecsherim or any modern day Poskim you are aware of and why sources would be appreciated?

Comment: I don't know a lot about sushi, but isn't most sushi raw? Does this Sushi _have to be_ seared or is that just the style of serving? My question is, can this sushi be eaten raw if you wanted to?

Comment: Yes Sushi is Nechal Aich SHehu CHai (one part of this question is does the fact that we eat sushi today change Halacha when the Gemara in Shabbos says Raw fish is Muktzeh because it has no use) but I want to know what the POSKIM say or the  HECSHERIM opinion on it

Comment: I believe according to S"A it would requite Bishul Yisrael.

Answer (score 4):

Per the [cRc](http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/kosher_sushi.php) it does not require Bishul Yisroel

> Generally speaking, if a non-Jew cooks a food in a country wherein
>   that food is eaten raw, then that food remains permitted to the kosher
>   consumer regardless of where it is eaten. This is because food that is
>   eaten raw is precluded from being bishul akum and, subsequently, the
>   non-Jew's cooking is not considered to be a meaningful act. Thus the
>   food was effectively not cooked by a non-Jew and is not, and can never
>   become, bishul akum

Per the [KOR Detroit](http://cordetroit.com/Portals/cor/pdf/KosherGram%20January2011.pdf)  since tuna can be eaten in its raw form, e.g. sushi, it is exempt from Bishul Yisroel

Comment: This misrepresents the article, which goes on to say: "Does this translate to sushi? Although raw fish is certainly eaten raw in the Orient, and increasingly so in America, the Poskim have ruled that the popularity of sushi has yet to change fish's requirement for bishul yisroel for the following reasons:"

Comment: The second link is dead.